# Sticky блок в sidebar responsive, при скроле до конца блока останавливался а не исчезал

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

```
var a = $(".sticks");
if (a.length > 0) var b = a.height(),
    c = a.offset().top - 90;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (a.length > 0) {
        var d = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (c < d) {
            a.css("top", d - c);
            var e = a.offset().top + b,
                f = $("main").offset().top + $("main").height();
            if (f < e) {
                var g = $("main").height() - b;
                a.css("top", g)
            }
        } else a.css("top", "0")
    }
}), $(window).resize(function() {
    a.length > 0 && (b = a.height())
})
```

Приветствую, нужна помощь, имеется код который работает, но при скроле до конца основного блока он исчезает, мне нужно, чтобы этот блок останавливался и дальше не ехал и не исчезал.

Comment: Господи, вы что, сразу обфусцированный код пишите?

Comment: Нет, данный код был сжат js компрессором.

Comment: Блок исчезал из-за c = a.offset().top - 90; переместил сюда a.css("top", d - c - 90); блок перестал исчезать, но теперь он скролит за footer, как эту часть if (f < e) {
                var g = $("main").height() - b;
                a.css("top", g)
            } переписать, чтобы он останавливался в конце блока?